# VSCode: use WSL Git instead of Git for Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use WSL (Bash on Windows) Git with VSCode instead of Git for Windows to avoid multiple Git installations.

I created a simple bat script to emulate `git.exe` comportment by redirecting git commands in WSL. It works nicely in CMD but not with VSCode. Also, WSL is my default terminal in VSCode.

VSCode **settings.json**:

```json
{
    "git.path": "D:\\tools\\git.bat",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe"
}
```

and **git.bat**:

```bat
@echo off
bash -c 'git %*'
```

Any idea to make VSCode working with WSL Git ?

Comment: The odd thing to me is that this approach works for ruby, rubocop, and every other executable I've tried.  I don't understand why it does not work for git.

Comment: Here is the official solution: <https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl>. Essentially, you just need to install the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension). The only quirk I have experienced is that it will start you off in bash even though you execute `code .` in zsh.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since VS Code 1.34 (April 2019) a remote extension has been introduced to develop into WSL: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl.

Basically, a server instance of VS Code is started into WSL, allowing you to use all the WSL tools (e.g. git) from your client instance on Windows.

*Thank you for pointing that out [@Noornashriq Masnon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441830/vscode-use-wsl-git-instead-of-git-for-windows?noredirect=1#comment101130755_44441830)!*

Comment: Awesome. After installing the extension, closing code and restarting code from wsl terminal, it downloaded server version and worked out of the box.

Comment: I also needed to run `code .` from inside a WSL terminal, this triggered a download needed to work properly.

Answer (score 22):

I created a small tool to solve this for myself, and [hosted it on GitHub](https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit).

Basic git functionality seems to work, like viewing changes and committing.

A ready-to-use binary can be downloaded [from the Releases page](https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit/releases).

One of the problems is that the input paths need to be translated from the Windows representation (`C:\Foo\Bar`) to the Linux paths in WSL (`/mnt/c/Foo/Bar`), and back again for paths in the output of git.

For example, the Git plugin in VSCode uses the command

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

to find the root directory of the git repository, but with WSL git this of course returns a Linux path that needs to be translated for VSCode on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, your exe works perfectly!
I had not thought about the paths problem. I will try to solve this issue in my script and post the solution here when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the full path for the bash exec :

**git.bat** :

```
@echo off
c:\windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c "git %*"
```

Comment: This solution doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Gut to mention that this git.bat should be somewhere in your PATH, also `wsl git %*`  will also work

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to first try `wslpath` and if that fails you try a normal `git` command. It's not ideal but it works.

See: [Use WSL git inside VS Code from Windows 10 17046](https://gist.github.com/victor-perez/8ba25540394ec68b11f4b2699fb4d4ce)