# Use git installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed `git` through WSL2:

```
Arch Linux on Windows 10 x86_64 with 4.19.84-microsoft-standard
 $ which git
/usr/sbin/git
```

From `cmd` I can either use git via `wsl.exe git ...` or via a batch file I made to access wsl programs:

```
 > wsl git status
On branch next
...
 > git.bat status
On branch next
...
```

However `git` does not work:

```
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe
Git installation not found.
```

**What I tried so far:**

- I moved my `git.bat` to C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.bat
- I put an explicit git path in the settings json:

  {
      "git.enabled": true,
      "git.path": "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe git",
      // ...
  }

Which does not work either:

```
Looking for git in: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe git
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe
Git installation not found.
```

What can I do if I **don't** want to install `git` for Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it using

- [VSCode: use WSL Git instead of Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441830/vscode-use-wsl-git-instead-of-git-for-windows?rq=1)
- https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit